# My bot sends an embed that is invisible to all users and shows no message sent

Tags: discord

I've been working on using JS to create a simple Discord Bot for my server. I have been trying to have it send a message with the rules of the server embedded into it. When the /rules command is run, I receive a notification to state a message was sent, but there is no message to be seen on any device. I am able to view message history so I do not understand why there is no visible embed or message.

My code was made using Autocode's Discord Embed Builder, and has worked for other embeds within the same Bot. A link to view the full embed code in the Builder and see how it is supposed to look is [here](https://autocode.com/tools/discord/embed-builder/?embed=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).

Comment: Do not add SOLVED to your title. If the problem is solved, give an answer or delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much easier to learn to make these yourself than using a generator and trying to reverse engineer how their coding works:

a simple example would be this:

```js
const {
    MessageEmbed
} = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: "rules",
    description: "Post rules",

    run: async (client, interaction) => {

// build the message
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#00ff00') //change the color if you want
            .setTitle('Some Title')
            .setDescription(`Some description`)
            .addFields({
                name: 'Rule Name/Number',
                value: 'Rule text',
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: 'Rule Name/Number',
                value: `Rule text`,
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: 'Rule Name/Number',
                value: 'Rule text',
                inline: true
            })
// add more if needed


// send the message
        interaction.channel.send({
            embeds: [embed]
        })

// confirm they are sent and complete the interaction only visible to you
        return interaction.reply({
            content: 'Done',
            ephemeral: true
        })
    }
}
```